# Analyzing twitter packets

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture, packet-analyzer, packet-sniffer, twitter

Thanks for your time. I'd like to find a way if a client has made a 'GET' or a 'POST' request for twitter.

We are currently doing an educational project and we wanted to understand how we can achieve this.

**Setup:**

1. We are using **Wireshark for Sniffing twitter's traffic.**
2. We are getting a lot of data packets, the question is: How do i differentiate between a GET and a POST request? Is this possible?

**Note**: I understand that Twittter uses HTTPS to encrypt traffic. But, if i'm not mistaken, POST/GET call(request) happens before the certificate exchange. I'm just interested if the call is GET/POST. (I'm not interested in data)

Thanks,
R

Comment: First, you will need to decrypt the SSL traffic.

Comment: I understand. I don't want any data from the traffic. I'm not interested in the data. But, I believe GET/POST call is made before the certificate exchange happens. I just want to understand if the user has made a "GET" call or a "POST" call

Comment: That is very much incorrect.

Comment: Thanks @EEAA for clarifying. Could you please enlighten? I'm sorry I'm just learning programming and I'm very new. I'd really appreciate if you can correct me.

Comment: if you tried what you propose, you could look in wireshark and use a filter of https and look at the packets directly. You would see the method is not available to you.

Comment: Can we speak of anything using Packet size, Payload Length or any other information that we have? Are they any different for GET/PUT/POST request? Even an approximation would be nice.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot decipher HTTPS traffic unless you do one of the following:

1. Have the private key
2. Do a Man-In-The-Middle attack where you intercept the SSL request, pretend to be the end client, decrypt it, inspect it, and then re-encrypt the data with your own root certificate and send it on to your end-client that trusts your root certificate.

What you can glean from the request:

- Source IP
- Source Port
- Destination IP
- Destination Port
- Hostname (if the server, and the client, are using [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication))

Let's assume that you have a method of reading this HTTPS traffic, or are using regular HTTP. Then you need to read up on your [RFC2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) to see how a HTTP packet is structured. Wireshark can decode these natively, so in the header you would see a `GET` or a `POST` directive.